# How do I use saz-sudo puppet module to deploy my own sudoers file with hiera?

Tags: puppet, sudo, hiera

I have saz-sudo installed and have created a site_sudo module based (I hope) on it.
Here's what I have in my site_sudo/manifest/init.pp file:

```
class { 'site_sudo': }
    sudo::conf { 'web':
      source => 'puppet:///files/etc/sudoers',
    }
    sudo::conf { 'syseng':
      priority => 10,
      content  => "%sysadm ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL",
    }

include sudo
```

No matter what I do, the sudoers file on the target is always overwritten with the sudoers.rhel6 file from saz-sudo module.

I'm using common.yaml too:

```
classes:
  - site_sudo
```

Comment: You really should not indent your `sudo::conf` declarations like that, seeing as they are in the same context as the `class {}` and `include` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that an exact copy from your file?  The `class { 'site_sudo': }` line would include that class into the config, not define the class as you should be doing in the `init.pp` for the module.  This will prevent the rest of the config in the file from being applied (since this file is only being evaluated to load that class; the other lines won't be evaluated as they would in an `import` statement).

Instead, it should look like this:

```
class site_sudo { 
  include sudo
  sudo::conf { 'web':
    source => 'puppet:///files/etc/sudoers',
  }
  sudo::conf { 'syseng':
    priority => 10,
    content  => "%sysadm ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL",
  }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that the `import` statement is deprecated and will be removed soon: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_import.html

Comment: You got confused by the bad indenting by the OP. `class { 'site_sudo': }` is an awkward way of saying `include site_sudo`, and not in fact defining the `class`. If you *would* want to define it, you would need to do away with the `:` and move the `{` to the end of the line - `class site_sudo { ... }`

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the help. I typed import when I meant to type include :P

Comment: So this sufficed to stop the module from overwriting `sudoers`? Weird.

Comment: @FelixFrank Yeah - he was saying it was the `site_sudo`'s `init.pp`, so I was thinking defining the class was the desired result.  Forgot to fix all the syntax for that.  I think there's some tricky logic in that `sudo` module which will drop a default config in if none of its defined types are realized or some such trickery (more clever and opaque than I would like..), causing that behavior.

Comment: @FelixFrank Oh, yes, you covered that in your answer!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [README](https://github.com/saz/puppet-sudo#purge-sudoersd-directory-but-leave-sudoers-file-as-it-is), you need to send a parameter to the `sudo` class:

```
class { 'sudo':
  config_file_replace => true,
}
```

instead of plain

```
include sudo
```

which clobbers `/etc/sudoers` as [stated](https://github.com/saz/puppet-sudo#purge-current-sudo-config).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [README](https://github.com/saz/puppet-sudo#using-puppet-version-27) and class [sudo::configs](https://github.com/saz/puppet-sudo/blob/master/manifests/configs.pp).

The used convention is rather strange (IMHO it would be easier to just add a hash parameter to class sudo)... but it seems to work quite well with Hiera.

For your example values:

```
classes:
  - sudo 
  - sudo::configs

sudo::configs:
    'syseng':
        'priority'  : 10
        'content'   : "%sysadm ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL"
```

Answer (score 0):

saz/sudo is designed to use a sudoers.d file and #include that. This is why it overwrites your sudoers file with a clean one, to be sure that it's the correct file. Those sudo::conf declarations will cause a file to show up in /etc/sudoers.d instead of changing /etc/sudoers directly.